# Thymealeaf text template not printing the current date

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-8, thymeleaf

I am using spring boot 2.2.4 and using the thymealeaf text templates for the first time with spring boot.

Belowis the texttemplate I am trying to use and I am trying to print the current date and time but it is printing blank on screen.

```
CurrentDate:[#th:block th:utext="${#temporals.format(now, 'dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm')}"/]
```

I have added the Java8 date time dependency in pom.xml and also added the java8dialect in the template resolver bean.

```
pom.xml
--------
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-java8time</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

ThymeleafConfig.java
----------------------

@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfig {

@Bean(name = "textTemplateEngine")
public TemplateEngine textTemplateEngine() {
   TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
   templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(textTemplateResolver());
   templateEngine.addDialect(new Java8TimeDialect());
   return templateEngine;
}

private ITemplateResolver textTemplateResolver() {
   ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
   templateResolver.setPrefix("/templates/text/");
   templateResolver.setSuffix(".txt");
   templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.TEXT /* https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/395 */);
   templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF8");
   templateResolver.setCheckExistence(true);
   templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
   return templateResolver;
 }
}
```

Can anybody please tell me what am I doing wrong in thymealeaf text template that it is not printing the date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Thymeleaf utility method](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#dates) to print various date and time variants.

For example:

```
<div th:text="${#dates.createNow()}"></div>
```

I think that may answer your specific question.

However, I suspect your question is more about the wider topic of binding Java objects to Thymeleaf templates in Spring - and I have not used Spring with Thymeleaf.